# Elastic search search + categorize the records

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  'query':
  {'bool':
  {'filter':
  [
  {'term':
  {'main_category': 'Easter Gifts'}
    
  }
  ],
  'must':
  [
    {'match':
    {'title':
    {'query': 'Grad', 'fuzziness': 'AUTO'}
      
    }
      
    }
    ]
    
  }
    
  },
  'size': 10, 
  'from': 0,
  'sort': [
    {'price': {'order': 'asc'}
      

    }
    ]}
```

for above query, i want to search in title and main_category both, it shouldn't return any hits because 'grad' search record doesn't exist in main_category 'Easter Gifts' but it still returns record

basically, i've an API that'll search according to the filters (title and category), title search working perfectly but search in category not working

I also want query for category products, like i'm listing category, if someone selects that category, all products of that category will be displayed